# Multithreading/Database Polling in Windows Service

Tags: .net, multithreading, windows-services, polling, task-parallel-library

This will be a long, 2 part question, so thanks for bearing with me and for any help.

I'm creating a windows service (.net 4) that has a few responsibilities:

- Poll database table, looking for items to process
- Queuing items for processing
- Process files on disk (the database table being polled describes the files being processed (file path, processing status))
- Record processing results to database
- Notify people when processing events take place (processing complete, processing errors)

The processing time for each item is assumed to take a long time (hours), so processing should take place on its own thread and multiple items should be processed concurrently (though probably not all items in the queue if the queue has a lot of items).

I'm not an expert in multithreading, but it seems that this project requires it for the database polling and the file processing.

I think I should use the Task Parallel Library, but don't really know where to start coding this application.

**How should I go about polling the database?**

Here's an idea for a database polling class that I had:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Timers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class DbPoller
{
    Timer _timer;
    public double Interval { get; private set; }

    public DbPoller(double interval)
    {
        Interval = interval;
    }

    public void BeginPolling()
    {
        if (_timer != null)
        {
            _timer.Dispose();
        }

        _timer = new Timer(Interval);
        _timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);
        _timer.Start();
    }

    public void EndPolling()
    {
        if (_timer != null)
        {
            _timer.Dispose();
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<BatchMetadata> Poll()
    {
        var pollTask = new Task<IEnumerable<BatchMetadata>>(() =>
        {
            // polling logic here
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        });

        pollTask.Start();
        return pollTask.Result;
    }

    void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Poll();
    }
}
```

**How should I manage the processing of multiple items?**

This is an area I'm even more unsure about. Like I said above, I think the file processing should happen on its own thread. Also, I think I should process some items concurrently (though not all in the queue, if there are very many). I know the TPL has a thread safe queue class that could possibly help me. I believe that it's my responsibility to manage how many items are processed concurrently, or does the TPL have features to help with that as well?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps SQL Server Reporting Services might have a solution for you that will not require you to poll the database but will allow you to respond to changes in the database.

As for processing jobs, TPL can do that but using Windows Workflow might be an option too.

It all depends on what kind of processing needs to be done and how long a job will take.